# bash - Unzip specific type of files from multiple zip

Tags: bash, unzip

I have 5 zip files and inside each of them are a few `.txt` files and a few others. I want to unzip only those files with extension `.txt`, but in the first iteration of the loop `unzip` runs correctly with "*.txt" treated as a constant string and in all subsequent iterations `unzip` tries to unzip files with exactly the same filename (ie those files which were in the previous zip file).

```
for file in *.zip
do
    unzip ${file} *.txt
done
```

As an example, in the first loop it takes `1.zip` and unzips e.g. `file1.txt` then it goes to the second loop, it takes `2.zip` and tries to extract `file1.txt` again - instead choosing all the `.txt` files from 2.zip.

Comment: What doesn't work about the example that you have given?

Comment: In first loop it takes 1.zip and unzip e.g. file1.txt then it goes to second loop, it takes 2.zip and try to unzip also file1.txt - instead taking .txt files from 2.zip.

Comment: Are you saying that the txt files inside the second and subsequent zip files have the same name as the first, and are overwriting them?

Comment: No, in each zip, .txt files names are different.
In 1.zip I have file1.txt, in 2.zip file2.txt, but when it is in second loop it doesn't update this "*.txt" name and unzip only file1.txt (which doesn't exist in this zip).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to protect your wildcard pattern with single quotes, otherwise the shell will expand it (this is called [globbing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob)):

```
for file in *.zip; do
    unzip ${file} '*.txt'
done
```

During the first iteration of the loop, `*.txt` doesn't expand to anything as there are no txt files in the working directory, so the command works as expected. After the first iteration, it expands to *all the txt files you just extracted from the first zip file*, so the second and subsequent iterations actually look something like this after globbing:

```
unzip ${file} file1.txt
```